# Sub rows within complex tables

Tags: tables

There's a table view we need to show in a Web app. It contains summaries of a company's listings on eBay.

Because of the volume of information, a standard columned table won't work - it just gets too long. Instead, I've created a mockup where some items sit on a subrow in the table.

I've explored the idea of having the additional information toggleable (see bottom row). Is there any other direction or amends you could think off? Any examples you've seen of large, complex table?

Opinions and thoughts welcome!

http://cl.ly/image/40272v160W30

Answer (score 1):

You could use another div to display detailed information, instead of toggleing.
This would "calm" the table, because the rows don't change size.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/binding.html

Comment: http://rememberthemilk.com do a pretty good version of this with a properties box off to the right

Answer (score 0):

If you do have togglable rows then I'd suggest that you add some shading below the expanded row to give a clearer distinction that it is a sub-row.

e.g. (Sorry its a pretty poor screenshot) but you can see the shading beneath the row.

[image]